# Get Modal presented view controller height ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, ios13

As you know in iOS 13 Modal presentation default has changed from full screen.

---

I need to know how should I calculate the presented ViewController's height because some of my views are now out of bounds.

```
guideLabel.frame = CGRect(x : padding , y : view.frame.maxY - 70 , width : view.frame.width - padding*2 , height : 70)
```

this is the code for placing the label that is in bottom of screen and as you see half of it is now outside of screen.

[image]

I tried getting the frame but it will return the full-screen height

in presented View Controller `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` was equal to `view.frame.height` although it is not.

I create all of my UI with code and with frames.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you...

**Found The Answer**

I just had to call my setupView() method in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    setupView()
}
```

instead of

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupView()
}
```

Comment: Did you try with autolayout?

Comment: Doing any calculations based on UIScreen bounds was always wrong. Always base layout on `self.view.bounds. Use constraints or at least update layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` based on `self.view.bounds`.